# editable table in jsp whose rows(may be more than one row) on updation are updated in database

Tags: java, jsp

I need to develop an jsp application where I need to bring data from database table and display it in table in frontend dynamically. I need to make this table editable. The user can edit any number of rows which all should be updated in the database table automatically on clicking Save Changes button.

I am able to bring data from database table and display it. I am displaying the values obtained from table in each cell of input type text of form. We am i clicking edit button i am able to update only last edited row in the table.
 Please tell how to update all the edited rows at a time.

Comment: *I am able to bring data from database table and display it. I am not able to make the table editable.* **What have you tried?** *Please tell me is it possible to update multiple rows at a time in the database from the values edited in the front end table.* **Yes.**

Comment: I have created a form and displayed values retrived from the database. On clicking update button i am able to retrieve the values of last edited row. can you tell me how to update multiple rows at a time in the database from the values edited.

Comment: I recommend you to reformulate the question then. You're basically asking a question which can only be answered with "yes" or "no". The answer is in this case simply "yes". It is definitely possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Provide two links for view and edit
  of table values
- In view keep the values simply in td element of table.
- In edit , use input elements of type text inside td element.
- If you want to do everything in same page, Ajax can be used for both view and edit.

Comment: Keep all the rows which are edited in JSON object and pass it to a servlet.In servlet parse the JSON object using various Json libraries.

Comment: Other than Ajax probably servlets can be used to update the edited rows in database by making use of DAO's and Bean classes.